# Which side of assignment expression is processed first?

Tags: c++, exception, stdmap

Consider this code:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::string> data;
data[5] = foo();
```

In what order are `data[5]` and `foo()` processed? If `foo()` throws an exception, is the `5` item in `data` created or not?

If the behaviour depends on version of C++, how do those versions differ?

Comment: Which version of C++?  It matters for this.

Comment: Assume it's undefined, and you won't be surprised whatever the result

Comment: This is covered in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46171943/4342498) updated for the change in C++17.  Not 100% sure if it should be closed as a dupe though

Comment: see [Order of evaluation of assignment statement in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33598938/1708801) ... for all the C++17 changes we can also see [What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38501587/1708801)

Comment: @NathanOliver this case is not undefined behavior though/

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour which is the main reason why I didn't close it as a dupe.  I actually think it would be nice to have this behavior documented as it's own Q&A.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Although with those links you found we should probably close this as a dupe of both of them.

Comment: The other interesting aspect of this case is that the map grow could also throw a memory exception, so the temporary result from foo had better have good RAII semantics, if you expect to recover perfectly.