# C++17 sequencing in assignment: still not implemented in GCC?

Tags: gcc, c++17, assignment-operator, sequencing

I tried the following code as a naive attempt to implement swapping of `R` and `B` bytes in an `ABGR` word

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t ABGR_to_ARGB(uint32_t abgr)
{
  return ((abgr ^= (abgr >> 16) & 0xFF) ^= (abgr & 0xFF) << 16) ^= (abgr >> 16) & 0xFF;
}

int main() 
{
    uint32_t tmp = 0x11223344;
    printf("%x %x\n", tmp, ABGR_to_ARGB(tmp));
}
```

To my surprise this code "worked" in GCC in C++17 mode - the bytes were swapped

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43d0fc47f5539746

But it is not supposed to swap bytes! C++17 clearly states that the RHS of assignment is supposed to be [fully] sequenced before the LHS, which applies to compound assignment as well. This means that in the above expression each RHS of each `^=` is supposed to use the original value of `abgr`. Hence the ultimate result in `abgr` should simply have `B` byte XORed by `R` byte. This is what Clang appears to produce (amusingly, with a sequencing warning)

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb9bdc8ced1b5f13

A quick look at GCC assembly

https://godbolt.org/g/1hsW5a

reveals that it seems to sequence it backwards: LHS before RHS. Is this a bug? Or is this some sort of conscious decision on GCC's part? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I don't see an obvious bug in your code so I believe this is a gcc bug since [their status](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) is pretty clear that `P0145R3` is supported in 7 and the [release notes agree as well](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html#cxx). They at least got the more [obvious cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33598938/1708801) fixed. Clang and MSVS [seem to do the right thing](https://godbolt.org/g/MxU5HE)

Comment: Try `g++ -Wall`.

Comment: @n.m. it gives an unsequenced warning which I think is incorrect, since the new wording provides sequencing. Even if you remove that by using separate values it still does the same thing.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The warning just hints you about some kind of problem. A simpler reproduction is `int x = 1; (x *= (x+3)) *= (x+7);` It elicits the same warnings from both compilers and produces different results. – n.m. 5 mins ago

Comment: @n.m. it is ugly code, I would ask for a refactor in code review. I have enough doubts I won't put an answer, I would prefer a case that is obvious free of potential UB. This case [seems to show gcc doing the right thing](https://godbolt.org/g/Yma3jW).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour well obviously gcc thinks it's UB, but is it really?

Answer (score 3):

The exact same behavior is exhibited by `int a = 1; (a += a) += a;`, for which GCC calculates `a == 4` afterwards and clang `a == 3`.

The underlying ambiguity arises from this part of the standard (from working draft N4762):

> [expr.ass]: 7.6.18 Assignment and compound assignment operators
>
> Paragraph 1: The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a
>   modifiable lvalue as their left operand; their result is an lvalue referring to the left operand. The result in all
>   cases is a bit-field if the left operand is a bit-field. In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value
>   computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression.
>   The right operand is sequenced before the left operand. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced
>   function call, the operation of a compound assignment is a single evaluation.
>
> Paragraph 7: The behavior of an expression of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent to E1 = E1 op E2 except that E1 is
>   evaluated only once. In += and -=, E1 shall either have arithmetic type or be a pointer to a possibly
>   cv-qualified completely-defined object type. In all other cases, E1 shall have arithmetic type.

GCC seems to be using this rule to internally transfrom `(a += a) += a` to `(a = a + a) += a` to `a = (a = a + a) + a` (since `a = a + a` has to be evaluated only once) - and for this expression the sequencing rules are correctly applied.

Clang however seems to do that last transformation step differently: `auto temp = a + a; temp = temp + a; a = temp;`

Both compilers give a warning about this, though (from the original code):

- GCC: `warning: operation on 'abgr' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]`
- clang: `warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'abgr' [-Wunsequenced]`

So the compiler writers know about this ambiguity and decided to prioritize differently (GCC: Paragraph 7 > Paragraph 1; clang: Paragraph 1 > Paragraph 7).

This seems to be a defect in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Do not make things more complicated than necessary. You can swap the 2 components in a fairly straightforward way without painting yourself into dark corners of the language:

```
uint32_t ABGR_to_ARGB(uint32_t abgr) {
    constexpr uint32_t mask = 0xff00ff00;
    uint32_t grab = abgr >> 16 | abgr << 16;
    return (abgr & mask) | (grab & ~mask);
}
```

It also generates much better assembly than the original version. On x86 it uses single `rol` instruction for the 3 bitwise operators to produce `grab`:

```
ABGR_to_ARGB(unsigned int):
        mov     eax, edi
        and     edi, -16711936
        rol     eax, 16
        and     eax, 16711935
        or      eax, edi
        ret
```

Comment: The question is not about the best way to swap bytes in a word. The original code is not in any way intended to be a viable solution for the original problem. It was no more than an attempt to use the [formerly invalid] `a ^= b ^= a ^= b` trick and see what will happen.