# Is it safe to modify and access the same object in a shift operator expression under the new standard?

Tags: c++, operators, c++17, bit-shift

As I may know that shift operator `<<` doesn't guarantee the order of evaluation of it its operands so an expression like this:

```
int i = 0;
cout << i << i++ << endl; // UB
```

But I think the new standard C++17 adds the shift operator to sequenced operators which guarantees to evaluates its `lhs` operand then its `rhs`.

So the expression above if compiled using C++17 or C++20 it will be ok:

```
int i = 0;
cout << i << i++ << endl; // 00
```

- But when I compile it using GCC and CLang passing `-std=c++17` and `-std=c++2a` I get the same warning `operation on 'i' maybe undefined [-Wsequence-point]`.

So Is it safe to do so or it is UB that I should never do? Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't do it even if it is well-defined, because it's not *immediately* obvious to the reader what is going on/what you *intended* to do. Avoid pre/postfix increments in the middle of other expressions.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I don;t think so because in the standard it is well-defined and  sequenced: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51784836/shift-operands-sequenced-in-c17 This is from the link above to my question.

Comment: Code is read more often than it is written; if you have to ask "what is this code doing, and did the programmer mean to do that?" then you've failed at writing readable code. It is unreasonable to expect a programmer to know enough about the language to know exactly what this code will do simply by inspection.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Why it is well-defined by the new standard then?

Comment: Having certain operators mandate sequencing is mainly intended to make fold expressions based on those operators be reliable. Also, there are cases where a value is being invisibly modified (such as `this->func1() << this->func2()`). It's not obviously apparent that these member functions modify the same member variable. But if you are *visibly* modifying the same thing in an expression... just don't.