# Assignment in C++ occurs despite exception on the right side

Tags: c++, c++14

I have some (C++14) code that looks like this:

```
map<int, set<string>> junk;
for (int id : GenerateIds()) {
    try {
        set<string> stuff = GetStuff();
        junk[id] = stuff;
    } catch (const StuffException& e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This works. Sometimes `GetStuff()` throws an exception, which works fine, because if it does, I don't want a value in the junk map then.

But at first I'd written this in the loop, which doesn't work:

```
junk[id] = GetStuff();
```

More precisely, even when `GetStuff()` throws an exception, `junk[id]` is created (and assigned an empty set).

This isn't what I'd expect: I'd expect them to function the same way.

Is there a principle of C++ that I've misunderstood here?

Comment: Also see [c++ map exception safe insert](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+map+exception+safe+insert) and [Making operations on standard-library containers strongly exception safe](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2a6a/30b9f7cd82ef29b64fbecae10463d533a6da.pdf), [Exception Safety: Concepts and Techniques](http://www.stroustrup.com/except.pdf), etc.

Comment: See [Order of evaluation of assignment statement in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33598938/1708801) also related [Does this code from “The C++ Programming Language” 4th edition section 36.3.6 have well-defined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27158812/1708801) and [What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38501587/1708801)

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers with similar problems: **no assignment happens here**. `junk[id]` creates a new `set`, yes, but that is using the default constructor. That's why the set is empty. This empty set would have been used as the object to assign to, if `GetStuff()` would have succeeded. But the exception thrown is precisely why no assignment happens. The set is left in its default state. It is a proper C++ object, and you can call its members normally. I.e. `junk[id].size()` will be 0 afterwards.

Comment: @MSalters Good clarification!  I used "assignment" too loosely (but "default constructed" was maybe a bit heavy for the question title ;-).

Comment: To make this even more safe (and more efficient), the assignment should be `junk[id] = std::move(stuff);` .

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Before C++17 there was no sequencing between the left- and right-hand side of assignment operators.

It's first in C++17 that explicit sequencing was introduced (right-hand side is evaluated first).

That means the evaluation order is *unspecified*, which means it's up to the implementation to perform the evaluation in the order in which it wants, and in this case it evaluates the left-hand side first.

See [this evaluation order reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) for more details (especially point 20).

Comment: If I understand the reference correctly the first sentence in the answer could be shortened by removing "overloaded", as right-hand-side is evaluated first for both overloaded and non-overloaded assignment operators in C++17.

Answer (score 17):

> std::map::operator[]
>
> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to
>   key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

`junk[id]` causes the above mentioned insertion and after that has already happened `GetStuff()` throws. Note that in C++14 the order in which these things happen is implementation defined so with a different compiler your `junk[id] = GetStuff();` may not do the insertion if `GetStuff()` throws.

Answer (score 12):

You're misunderstanding how `operator[]` works on `std::map`.

It returns a reference to the mapped item.  Therefore, your code is first inserting a default item in that position and then invoking `operator=` to set a new value.

To make this work the way you expect, you'll need to use `std::map::insert` (*):

```
junk.insert(std::make_pair(id, GetStuff()));
```

*Caveat*: `insert` will only add the value if `id` is not already mapped.

Comment: i dont think there is any misconception about how `operator[]` works involved here. Also from your answer its not clear why `operator=` evaluates the left hand side, even if the right hand side throws an exception

Comment: If there is any misunderstanding, it would for me be a misunderstanding for a[b]=...; not just for a[...].

Comment: @user463035818: The questioner expresses a belief that an assignment occurred, which strongly suggests they are unaware that evaluating the `operator[]` would create an empty set for `junk[id]` on its own.

Comment: Upvoted for suggesting a way to write it without first default-constructing an entry, regardless of whether there's a "misunderstanding" or not.