# Why is the execution order different in addition and subtraction?

Tags: c++, operators, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

I have a function that takes one argument by address and changes the value of the argument. But when I call the function, the order of execution is different in cases of addition and subtraction:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int *i) {
    *i += 5;
    return 4;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    x = x + fun(&x);
    cout << "x: " << x << endl;
    
    int y = 3;
    y = y - fun(&y);
    cout << "y: " << y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is:

> x: 12
>
> y: -1

which means `x` is first changed in the function and then added to itself (I expected `x` to become `7`), but the changes on `y` don't affect the `y` before subtraction operator.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is it defined behavior? If not, anything goes and you can't complain.

Comment: The evaluation order of operator and function arguments is unspecified. `fun(&x)` may be  evaluated before `x` and vise versa. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598938/order-of-evaluation-of-assignment-statement-in-c

Comment: Looks like this is [entry #2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Undefined_behavior) in the "undefined behavior" section here.

Comment: @S.M. And because `fun(&x)` has a side effect on `x`, the resulting code is actually UB not merely unspecified.

Comment: @S.M. does it mean the output can change at different runs? Because currently, the output is (12, -1) every time I run it.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk does it mean the output can be different if I run it again?

Comment: It means you don't know what could happen to the output for each run.

Comment: Yes, it means it can be different on different runs. I wouldn't expect it to be, but I'd consider any program with undefined behavior to be a buggy and in need of repair.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad -- You're concerned about different runs -- how about with different compiler options, compiler versions of the same compiler, or different compiler brands altogether?  You write code like this for version x of the compiler, you upgrade to version y, and then all of a sudden, your program is broken.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks. I tested this with different compilers and different versions of C++ and every time the output was the same. I thought there might be a rule for the `+` and `-` operators, but now I know it is undefined behavior.