# Why does std::unique_ptr<>.release() get evaluated before member function access which is in the lhs of assignment?

Tags: c++, c++20

This results in a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) when accessing unique_ptr->get_id() as release() is run beforehand.

Is the ordering not guaranteed here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

class D
{
private:
        int id_;
public:
        D(int id) : id_{id} { std::cout << "D::D\n"; }
        ~D() { std::cout << "D::~D\n"; }

        int get_id() { return id_; }

        void bar() { std::cout << "D::bar\n"; }
};

int main() {
        std::unordered_map<int, D*> obj_map;
        auto uniq_ptr = std::make_unique<D>(123);

        obj_map[uniq_ptr->get_id()] = uniq_ptr.release();
        obj_map.at(123)->bar();

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33598938/580083

Comment: Off-topic: Assuming this would work (for the fix see answers) you are evaluating the hash twice, once for `operator[]`, once for `at` (why `at` at all? operator[] guarantees already existence, so no bounds checking necessary...), so you could instead do: `auto ptr = map[id] = release(); ptr->bar()` or even `(map[id] = release())->bar()` – though the latter might appear a bit *too* condensed...

Comment: This is just an example code I wrote; the actual use was quite different.

Comment: A much better approach would be holding `unique_ptr<D>` inside the map and doing `obj_map[uniq_ptr->get_id()] = std::move(uniq_ptr);`  This will steal ownership, releasing the object from the original pointer, but (a) do it in the correct sequence and (b) be exception-safe / prevent future leaks.  Right now if the map can't reallocate / increase number of hash buckets, the raw pointer to the object is lost / leaked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because of [[expr.ass]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ass#1) which states:

> [...] In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression. **The right operand is sequenced before the left operand**. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of a compound assignment is a single evaluation.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

According to the above the right hand side gets evaluated first, then the left hand side, then the assignment happens.  It should be noted that this is only guaranteed since C++17.  Before C++17 the order of the left and right sides evaluations was unspecified.

Comment: So you mean: `obj_map[uniq_ptr.release()->get_id()]=uniq_ptr.get();` is good with C++>=17.

Comment: @Red.Wave yes.  The RHS is guaranteed to be evaluated first, so the call to `get` will happen before `release`.

Answer (score 13):

It's actually guaranteed that this code *will always fail*.

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order):

> 20. In every simple assignment expression E1=E2 and every compound assignment expression E1@=E2, every value computation and side-effect of E2 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E1 (since C++17)

In other words: `release()` is guaranteed to be called before `get_id()` in your case.

Comment: Huh, missed that part of the standard change, have still been living in times of sub-expressions not being sequenced... One never stops learning ;)

Comment: Interesting enough: *14.* and *18.* together should have assured that we get the desired evaluation order by `obj_map[uniq_ptr->get_id()].operator=(uniq_ptr.release())`...

Comment: `obj_map[uniq_ptr->get_id()].operator=(uniq_ptr.release())` is a good trick to know. Though I don't like using operator methods directly

Comment: @MayurKulkarni Well, then get the id first and do assignment afterwards: `auto id = get(); map[id] = release();`...